# Use or translate an Expression Lambda to SQL? for Postgresql in a Where clause

Tags: c#, postgresql

Is it possible to translate or somehow use a C# Expression Lambda with Postgresql. I would like to use them as where clause predicates.
I have a query that looks like this:

```
var query = Expression.Lambda<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, bool>>(conditions, itemExpression);
```

The result could look something like this?

```
IsMatch(Convert(valueBag.Item["pnt_name"], String), "RP")
```

Thanks